# Close a dynamically created Log4j 2 appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm using the [Routing](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) functionality in Log4j 2 to dynamically create appenders at runtime.  When I know that those appenders are finished with, I'd like to tell Log4j so that it can tidy up the related resources (flush & close files, free its internal objects related to those appenders, etc.).  Without doing this, Log4j still has open file handles and I'm unable to manipulate the files that it has written (from an external process which post-processes and archives the logs).

**How do I tell Log4j that an appender won't be used again?**

I include my Log4j configuration for completeness.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>

    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level{ERROR=!, WARN=?, INFO=-, DEBUG=., TRACE=.} %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <Routing name="MatchLogs">
      <Routes pattern="$${ctx:matchID}">
        <Route>
          <RandomAccessFile name="MatchLog-${ctx:matchID}" fileName="logs/${ctx:matchID}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5level %-30.30logger{1} %msg%n"/>
          </RandomAccessFile>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Routing>
    <Async name="AsyncWrapper">
      <AppenderRef ref="MatchLogs" level="debug"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" level = "info"/>
    </Async>

    <Routing name="MatchStatsLogs">
      <Routes pattern="$${ctx:matchID}">
        <Route>
          <RandomAccessFile name="MatchStatsLog-${ctx:matchID}" fileName="logs/${ctx:matchID}_stats.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg"/>
          </RandomAccessFile>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Routing>
    <Async name="AsyncStatsWrapper">
      <AppenderRef ref="MatchStatsLogs" level="debug"/>
    </Async>

  </Appenders>


  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="stats" level="trace" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="AsyncStatsWrapper"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="AsyncWrapper"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>


</Configuration>
```

When a match starts, I call `ThreadContext.put("matchID", theMatchID);` from each thread that is involved in that match.  When a match finishes, I clear the `ThreadContext`.  Obviously that isn't sufficient for Log4j to know that I'm not going to re-use that match ID, so it keeps the Appender around.  However, I know that I'm not going to re-use the match ID, so how do I tell Log4j to tidy up?

Comment: Excellent question.  For this very reason I had to move to programmatically creating the appenders so I can close them when I'm done.  Something like a timeout or context expiration function would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4J does not provide that function yet. You may want to raise a feature request in the Log4J2 issue tracker (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2 ).

Comment: Just as update, this functionality has been implemented with Log4j2 v2.5. For the RoutingAppender as Purge Policy (see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender)

Comment: @philnate This is good info for routing appender. But, what about the dynamically created appenders?